# how ot import python modules by default?

Tags: python, import, module

Could you tell me, how add importing of python's modules by default? 99% of my scripts starts from

```
import os,sys,csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
```

Is it possible to tell python load all this modules by default? maybe it is possible just add these few lines into configuration file (something like .pyrc at home directory)?

Thanks,
~R

Comment: Don't do this. Your scripts will break in hard to identify ways.

Comment: @March, why?! What the difference? I'd like to import this modules before python will interpret any script. Probably locally only for local user.

Comment: Your scripts will have a dependency not discoverable from their face. You'll appear to have a bunch of non-standard builtins. Maintenance will be a nightmare, and your scripts will be non-portable. It's your own funeral, of course.

Comment: @Marcin Well if I wouldn't like to spread or maintain my script. what if they are just small tests. it's annoying to type EVERY time (including the console) 4-5 lines to import libs and then two lines to make a tiny test....

Comment: Then you'll have a hidden dependency in your tests. If that doesn't seem an obviously bad idea, I can't help you.

Answer (score 2):

if you write some python module, you can import it `__init__.py`

Comment: This is the only reasonable solution.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way to do it is that:

(1) run python to define your local directory for modules:

```
python -m site --user-site
```

(2) Then create this directory

```
mkdir -p <name of you local direcotry>
```

(3) create tiny file msite.py there

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Now we need only import everything from this file in our script:

```
$python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Aug 19 2011, 20:41:43) [GCC] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from msite import *
>>> np.linspace(0,10,11)
array([  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.])
>>>
```